# Wrong output when using 'groupby' for 'US/Eastern' zone

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timezone, pandas-groupby

Suppose that we have this code. `dd` is a date range with the frequency of 15 minutes and the `UTC` time zone. I add another column to the `data` dataframe by converting this column to the `US/Eastern` zone. Then use `groupby` for putting the rows together that start and end at 9:30:00 AM.

```
import pandas as pd
import pytz
import numpy as np
dd = pd.date_range(start='03/10/2018', end='03/12/2018', freq='15min', tz='UTC')

data = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(0, len(dd)))
data = data.set_index(dd)

est = pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')
data['EST_time'] = data.index.tz_convert(est)

output = list(data.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='EST_time', freq='24h', offset = '9:30:00')))
```

The problem is the second item of the `output` list. As you can see it starts at `2018-03-10 09:30:00-05:00` and ends at `2018-03-11 10:15:00-04:00`. the start time is correct (kind of), but the end time is after 9:30:00. Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a DST transition (winter to summer time) on Mar 11th, so that day (in that time zone) actually only had 23 hours, which is why freq='24h' won't work.

`freq='1d'` should do the trick:

```
for g in data.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='EST_time', freq='1d', offset = '9:30:00')):
    print(g[0])
    
2018-03-09 09:30:00-05:00
2018-03-10 09:30:00-05:00
2018-03-11 09:30:00-04:00
```